# How do I connect to my wi-fi in Lubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, settings

(Preface) Ive read all of the existing questions for Lubuntu and Wifi but only have more questions.
Im new to Linux. I've entered all the network-info in to the VPN-connections as best to my understanding, Im not a complete idiot when it comes to network-settings but I have experienced no joy.

I dont have internet conenction to the computer Im setting up Wifi for, so what do I do?

Comment: You need to give more information so that other can help you. Read http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos to know what info you'll have to provide.

Comment: Wireless info text , please http://paste.ubuntu.com/12306347/

Comment: probably you are missing drivers.  or, maybe, this question should be deleted.  It's unlikely that the OP will be able to provide details at this stage.